# Is it possible and how to recover scripts from the project Library or Build?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I had a crash on Unity while updating the PlayfabSDK with their Extension and after restarting the project (I didn't notice before) ALL my files were gone, assets, scripts, prefabs, everything. I only had the Playfab SDK. I've been using Unity for some years and never had a problem like this so I've stoped doing backups some months ago. I've learned the lesson now...

I've recovered the Library folder (did a copy yesterday) and I also have the game built as WebGL, also after Googling a lot and trying a lot of tools I recovered some assets from the Build and also I could find some scripts and some damaged ones using Pandora Recovery.

Some scripts are OK but others are completly broken or corrupted. It is possible to recover the scripts from the Library dlls?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you can fully recover scripts from the build. But in the future you can use a version control system to prevent this from being a problem. Unity has Unity collaborate built in,  you can use it or just setup GIT with a private repository somewhere.

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is that some IDEs keep a local history of changes. I know that JetBrains Rider and Eclipse do. Visual studio doesn't unless you download a plugin for that

Comment: Wow I'm sorry for you that sounds horrible! But yes as mentioned it is very hard to recover scripts in that situation .. the build is machine code and even if you would be able to somehow recover some code from it it will be the generated code without any readability so it would anyway probably not be much of use for you neither. I don't want to sound unfriendly really - If you work with Unity for some years already you either deserve a lot of respect or needed a punishment for doing it without any version control or backups. **All** coding should always happen under version control!

Comment: Yep that was a bug fail.. as I said Ive learned the lesson... Anyway this error/bug it's too critical. Reported it ont he Playfab bug forum and for some reason they hided my bug report and set it as "waiting for moderation"...

Good new about my problem is that I recovered around 70-80% of my scripts with Pandora. I dont know where it recovered the scripts files or how it did but saved me tons of hours of work even if some oof the scripts are partially corrupted.